# Disable instead of Visible = false for GridView TemplateField?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm currently hiding a `asp:TemplateField` column in my `GridView` with `GridViewEmps.Columns[12].Visible = false` from code-behind. And that's working correctly.

But instead of hiding it, I would like to disable (or read-only) the whole `GridView` column. And if that's too difficult, then disable the `DropDownList` (id `DropDownListActive`) within this column. The purpose is not being able to change the contents of the column under certain circumstances. For example, if a specific search is made, then this column is disabled. Otherwise, it's enabled for editing.

Here's the code that sets the visibility. I would like to change from visible to readonly/disabled:

```
protected void Btn_Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Bind gridview to DataTable

    string empStatus = this.DropDownListStatus.SelectedValue;

    if (empStatus == "N/A")
    {
        GridViewEmps.Columns[12].Visible = false;
    }
    else 
    {
        GridViewEmps.Columns[12].Visible = true;
    }
}
```

And the templatefield:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-Width="80px">
    <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListActive" SelectedValue='<%#Eval("Status")%>' runat="server">
         <asp:ListItem Text="N/A" Value="--" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Text="Active" Value="Active"></asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="LabelPrvStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PrevStatus") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Thanks.

Comment: GridViewEmps.Columns[12].ReadOnly = true; ? would that not work for you?

Comment: I don't see ReadOnly attribute in the vs2010 `autocomplete`.

Comment: Is this a bound column or are you generating it automatically? If it's bound you can put the read only attribute in the <asp:BoundColumn>

Comment: No, I posted it was a TemplateField.

Answer (score 0):

```
DropDownListActive.Enabled = false;
```

or

```
DropDownListActive.IsEnabled = false;
```

(depending on sdk version)

Impossible for the whole container, only for children controls.

Answer (score 0):

You said you are using a `TemplateField`, so why can't just disable the control in the markup?

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownListActive" Enabled="false" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**Edit**

With the information you are giving me and saying that

> You don't need to know when to enable or disable; you only need to
>   know that an IF statement sets the column to visible=true and and ELSE
>   sets the column to visible=false

this is the best I can, hope it helps

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownListActive" Enabled='<%# (int)Eval("ValueIDontNeedToKnow") == varToPassTheIfStatement) ? true : false %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I edited the question. It can't always be readonly. Depending on the search, it's disabled (or hidden as it's currently) or enabled for editing.

Comment: You said that *I would like to disable (or read-only) the whole GridView column*, edit your question, also, what did you mean by *if a specific search is made*, how do I know when to enable or disable?

Comment: You don't need to know when to enable or disable; you only need to know that an IF statement sets the column to visible=true and and ELSE sets the column to visible=false . But for the sake of argument, I've posted the code.